# Sequlize js how to do date comparison based on CURRENT_DATE

Tags: sequelize.js

excuting this on the phpMyAdmin gives me a one record.

```
SELECT * FROM `banners` WHERE region_id = 1 AND status= 'approved' and approved_date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

But I try to achive same thing using sequlize like this

```
const banners = await db.banners.findAll({
      where: {
        region_id: id,
        status: "approved",
        approved_date: new Date()
      }
    });
```

When I trace the query

SELECT `id`, `path`, `expire_date`, `status`, `fee`, `notes`, `approved_date`, `region_id`,
 `restaurant_id`, `is_paid`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `banners` AS `banners` 
WHERE `banners`.`region_id` = 1 AND `banners`.`status` = 'approved' AND
 `banners`.`approved_date` = '2018-10-11 17:29:31';

The problem I see is `approved_date` column data type is date and the comparison `new Date()`
both the date and the time. What is the similar key word to CURRENT_DATE in sequlize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a string directly to the `WHERE` condition, you can use `sequelize.literal`:

```
const banners = await db.banners.findAll({
  where: {
    $and: [
      {
        region_id: id,
        status: "approved"
      }
    ],
    sequelize.where(
      sequelize.fn('DATE', sequelize.col('approved_date')),
      sequelize.literal('CURRENT_DATE')
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer also works!

```
const banners = await db.banners.findAll({
      where: {
        region_id: id,
        status: "approved",
        approved_date: db.Sequelize.fn('CURRENT_DATE')

      }

    });
```